# PHP DOM Xpath get image

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm trying to get a image with php dom and xpath, but the image has no unique identifier which i can use to fetch it. I only need this 1 image.

The markup is as follows:

```
<img alt="Photo of Starbucks Raffles City" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: -11px;" id="HERO_PHOTO" class="flexibleImage" src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/02/39/57/0d/front-of-starbucks.jpg" width="256" height="171">
```

If i fetch on class or id it doesn't help much because more images have these classes, is there anyway to fetch on 3 properties at the same time? For example i want to find the //img where the id is A, the class is B and the width is C.
something like that?

Comment: You can think about other criterias as "after smthg" or sibling has some text....

Answer (score 0):

> "For example i want to find the //img where the id is A, the class is B and the width is C"

You can simply combine multiple criteria using `and` operator. For example, XPath for the above statement would be :

```
//img[@id='A' and @class='B' and @width='C']
```